# my ajax code doesnt send every row from php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

i have a php code that is load data from database answer table

php code :

```
 <?php while ($rowanswer=mysql_fetch_assoc($answer)) :?>
       <div  class="text-soal2">

        <div class="vote-svj">
                <div class="vote-svj-vt3"><a class="voteupa" onclick="" ><img src="images/plus.png" alt="like" title="+"/></a></div>
                <div class="vote-svj-vt2"><?php echo $rowanswer['vote'] ;
                echo $aid=$rowanswer['id'];
                ?></div>
                <div class="vote-svj-vt"><a class="votedowna" ><img src="images/minus.png" alt="dislike" title="-"/></a></div>

           </div>


         <div class="text-javab">


               <p>

             <?php echo $rowanswer['answer'] ?>



               </p>  


      </div><div class="clr"></div>
      <h5>نوشته شده توسط <?php 

      $query1="select username from user where id=$rowanswer[user_id]";
      $senderanswer=mysql_query($query1);
$ssender=mysql_fetch_assoc($senderanswer);

      echo $ssender['username'];

       ?> در تاریخ <?php echo $rowanswer['date'] ?></h5>
   </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

i effort to send  $aid=$rowanswer['id'] answer id with ajax to another page 
but it only send last aid to another page how can i send every row aid to with ajax when i click in it buttons

ajax code :

```
$('.votedowna').click(function(){
$.ajax({
         url : '<?php echo "php_func/answer_vote.php?aid=".$aid ?>',
         type : 'GET',

         data : { send : "dislike"},
        beforeSend : function()
        {
            alert(<?php echo $aid ?>);
            },
        success : function(callback){
            alert(callback);

        })


    });
```

Comment: What are trying to do? explain and we will help you.

Comment: Why not saving $rowanswer['id'] values in array(making $aid array),instead of putting it to regular variable? if you use normal variable,you overwrite it every time and have only last in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<div class="vote-svj-vt"><a class="votedowna" id="<?php echo $rowanswer['id'];"><img src="images/minus.png" alt="dislike" title="-"/></a></div>
```

And then in JS Just fetch that id that we added in `votedowna` anchor tag and pass it with url.

```
$('.votedowna').click(function(){
var aid = $(this).attr("id");
$.ajax({
         url : 'php_func/answer_vote.php?aid='+aid,
         type : 'GET',

         data : { send : "dislike"},
        beforeSend : function()
        {
            alert();
            },
        success : function(callback){
            alert(callback);

        })


    });
```

Comment: thank u for your code but what can i do for voteup ?
if i use it the ids will conflict with togeter ...

Comment: The ids should be unique and as far as vote up is concern, just where you see 3 votes on my answer you can click on arrow above 3 and also accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `.votedowna` repeats itself depending of the amount of the iterations your `while` loop has, you have to have an `.each` statement before the how you want to handle the `click` event.

```
$('.votedowna').each(function() {
 $(this).click(function() {
  $.ajax( ...
```

This might be the issue.
By the way, do you have create the Javascript code inside the `while` in PHP or do you have a `.js` file?
Because if you use a JS file then you have to pass the ajax URL differently, meaning your Javascript should look like this,

```
$.ajax({
     url : 'php_func/answer_vote.php',
     type : 'GET',

     data : { 
       send : "dislike",
       aid: $(this).parent().parent().find('div.vote-svj-vt2').text(), // This is where you have the aid for this row, you better save it somewhere else though
     },
    beforeSend : function()
    {
        alert('<?php echo $aid ?>');
        },
    success : function(callback){
        alert(callback);

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are trying to call an ajax method many times, you can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop to do it.

Second, please do not use `mysql_query` in your script, because it's too old. use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Finally, if you need to select anything in javascript many times you can use .each() instead of using .click

Also, use the standard query writing method like this

```
 SELECT username FROM user WHERE id= '$rowanswer[user_id]'
```